# Add a new child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my situation is a bit different to issues found online.

I want the node `Societies` to be updated with a new child node `Foot19` when the button is pressed. The context is that it is a list of school groups that when the user presses on the button to 'follow' them, the ID to that group is added to their personal data section.

So when they click `addFootballSoc` button `Foot19` is added as a new child node to their specific `Societies` node.

The key values in the at the start of each `sUsers` node is equivalent to their `authentication uid` which is why I'm calling it using `firebase.auth()`

[image: Screenshot of the area in my database I want to update with a new child]

```
document.getElementById('addFootballSoc').onclick = function() {addFootball()};

function addFootball(){
var runUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var searchRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
var newSearchRef = searchRef.child(runUid); 
var mm = newSearchRef.child('Societies')
mm.child.set('Foot19'){}
}
```

I want it to add a new child for each group they join so they can't overwrite  either, for example if I were to add a 'Arts' group button

EDIT:

changed the function so the onclick works and it does now write to where I want, 
however, if I were to add another child node alongside `Foot19` it will delete `Foot19` and replace it, I would use `push` but I don't want to have the unique key added to my nodes. How can I change this to ensure more nodes can be added?

```
document.getElementById('addFootballSoc').onclick = function() {addFootball()};

function addFootball(){
var runUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var searchRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
var newSearchRef = searchRef.child(runUid); 
var mm = newSearchRef.child('Societies')
mm.child.set('Foot19'){}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be calling the function immediately `addFootball()` on page load before you have the uid back/resolved from Firebase or looks like you are handing `.set` the wrong type of data. Try this.

```
document.getElementById('addFootballSoc').addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
var runUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
if(runUid){
var searchRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
var newSearchRef = searchRef.child(runUid); 
var mm = newSearchRef.child('Societies')
mm.child.set({'Foot19':true});
} else {
  console.log("no uid");
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've edited some of the code according to your suggestion, I can now write to the specific 'Socities' node but any new entries will overwrite the previous one in that child.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

[screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fsN9.jpg)

The screen grab shows the entries being placed in the child node `societies` within the users `ùid` node. The extra entires `ALT5` & `ASN11` are where I changed the value on line 6 to test that new nodes would not be overwritten.

```
function addFootball(){
var runUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
var searchRef = firebase.database().ref('sUsers');
var newSearchRef = searchRef.child(runUid); 
newSearchRef.child('Societies').update({
    Foot19 : true
})
}
```